# How to mix PartialFunction input parameter with output

Tags: function, scala, partialfunction

What is the best way to mix a function input parameter with the output.

Here is my current code :

```
def zip[A,B](f: A => B) : A => (A, B) = (a: A) => (a, f(a))
def zip[A,B](pf: PartialFunction[A,B]) : PartialFunction[A, (A, B)] = { 
  case a if pf.isDefinedAt(a) => (a, pf(a)) 
}
```

Is there a better way ?
Is there a better naming for that ?

Comment: Not really an answer, but with Scalaz's arrow this would just be `identity[A] _ &&& f`.

Comment: @TravisBrown  Scalaz... always so mysterious.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh With better type inference it would just be `id &&& f`, which I think is pretty clear—it just says "apply both of these functions to the same argument and pair the results".

Answer (score 0):

If you `lift` then `match`, you only have to evaluate `pf` once (unlike in your solution, which evaluates twice):

```
def zip[A,B](pf: PartialFunction[A,B]): PartialFunction[A, (A, B)] = 
    x => pf.lift(x) match { case Some(res) => x -> res }
```

Or you can use `unlift` which takes a function to `Option` and returns the equivalent `PartialFunction`:

```
def zip[A,B](pf: PartialFunction[A,B]) = Function.unlift((x:A) => pf.lift(x).map(x -> _))
```